# Mongo hashtable namespace index max chain error

Tags: mongodb, runtime-error

I'm having this error when I insert too much documents in a single instance mongodb:

```
11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
"Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
"Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
"Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335",
"Wed Apr  3 11:53:00.379 [conn1378573] end connection 127.0.0.1:40748 (1 connection now open)",
```

What's the meaning of this error, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many collections are you using? I'd suggest taking a look at [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-model-large-number-of-collections)

Comment: thanks, thats the cue. I was pretending to create 100.000 collections. I didn't know this limit.